# rails gem install pg

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, postgis

I want to install the gem pg onto my windows 7 machine with:

```
gem install pg
```

But it fails every time with following error:

```
Fetching: pg-0.14.1-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)
Successfully installed pg-0.14.1-x86-mingw32
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for pg-0.14.1-x86-mingw32...
Enclosing class/module 'rb_mPG' for class Connection not known
Enclosing class/module "rb_cPGconn" for alias close finish not known
Enclosing class/module "rb_cPGconn" for alias query exec not known
Enclosing class/module "rb_cPGconn" for alias escape escape_string not known
Enclosing class/module "rb_cPGconn" for alias nonblocking? isnonblocking not kno
wn
Enclosing class/module "rb_cPGconn" for alias client_encoding= set_client_encodi
ng not known
Enclosing class/module "rb_cPGconn" for alias notifies_wait wait_for_notify not
known
Enclosing class/module "rb_cPGconn" for alias async_query async_exec not known
Enclosing class/module "rb_cPGconn" for alias locreat lo_creat not known
Enclosing class/module "rb_cPGconn" for alias locreate lo_create not known
Enclosing class/module "rb_cPGconn" for alias loimport lo_import not known
Enclosing class/module "rb_cPGconn" for alias loexport lo_export not known
Enclosing class/module "rb_cPGconn" for alias loopen lo_open not known
Enclosing class/module "rb_cPGconn" for alias lowrite lo_write not known
Enclosing class/module "rb_cPGconn" for alias loread lo_read not known
Enclosing class/module "rb_cPGconn" for alias lolseek lo_lseek not known
Enclosing class/module "rb_cPGconn" for alias lo_seek lo_lseek not known
Enclosing class/module "rb_cPGconn" for alias loseek lo_lseek not known
Enclosing class/module "rb_cPGconn" for alias lotell lo_tell not known
Enclosing class/module "rb_cPGconn" for alias lotruncate lo_truncate not known
Enclosing class/module "rb_cPGconn" for alias loclose lo_close not known
Enclosing class/module "rb_cPGconn" for alias lounlink lo_unlink not known
Installing RDoc documentation for pg-0.14.1-x86-mingw32...
Enclosing class/module 'rb_mPG' for class Connection not known
Enclosing class/module "rb_cPGconn" for alias close finish not known
Enclosing class/module "rb_cPGconn" for alias query exec not known
Enclosing class/module "rb_cPGconn" for alias escape escape_string not known
Enclosing class/module "rb_cPGconn" for alias nonblocking? isnonblocking not kno
wn
Enclosing class/module "rb_cPGconn" for alias client_encoding= set_client_encodi
ng not known
Enclosing class/module "rb_cPGconn" for alias notifies_wait wait_for_notify not
known
Enclosing class/module "rb_cPGconn" for alias async_query async_exec not known
Enclosing class/module "rb_cPGconn" for alias locreat lo_creat not known
Enclosing class/module "rb_cPGconn" for alias locreate lo_create not known
Enclosing class/module "rb_cPGconn" for alias loimport lo_import not known
Enclosing class/module "rb_cPGconn" for alias loexport lo_export not known
Enclosing class/module "rb_cPGconn" for alias loopen lo_open not known
Enclosing class/module "rb_cPGconn" for alias lowrite lo_write not known
Enclosing class/module "rb_cPGconn" for alias loread lo_read not known
Enclosing class/module "rb_cPGconn" for alias lolseek lo_lseek not known
Enclosing class/module "rb_cPGconn" for alias lo_seek lo_lseek not known
Enclosing class/module "rb_cPGconn" for alias loseek lo_lseek not known
Enclosing class/module "rb_cPGconn" for alias lotell lo_tell not known
Enclosing class/module "rb_cPGconn" for alias lotruncate lo_truncate not known
Enclosing class/module "rb_cPGconn" for alias loclose lo_close not known
Enclosing class/module "rb_cPGconn" for alias lounlink lo_unlink not known
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like the gem has actually installed. It's the documnentation that comes afterwards that's caused it to blow up. If you do 'gem list' can you see it as being installed? If so, you should be able to use it as normal ...

it says:

```
Successfully installed pg-0.14.1-x86-mingw32
1 gem installed
```

Answer (score 6):

The failure happened installing the docs. This documentation is prone to error and you'll probably never read it anyway. It takes time and space to install, but a failure will leave a working gem, so you're OK here.

Try this to skip the doc installs:

```
gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri pg
```

Use the same pattern for other gem installs.